# Regular values of a complex map

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I'm trying to calculate regular values of the map $f:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $(z_1,\ldots,z_n)\mapsto \sum|z_i|^2$.

I know that for the map $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto \sum|x_i|^2$, the differential is given by the Jacobian with entries $dg/dx_j=2x_j$. Therefore the derivative is surjective for any $g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=y>0$ and hence the regular values are all $y>0$.

I'm not sure how to do this for the complex case, if we naively consider $\mathbb{C^n}$ as $\mathbb{R^{2n}}$ do we not lose the complex structure?

Comment: But the complex structure doesn't matter. If you don't want to use real coordinates, you'll need to consider both $z_j$ and $\bar z_j$ derivatives to get the $2n$ necessary tangent directions.

Comment: Is this correct for taking $z,\overline{z}$ derivatives $\partial / \partial z |z|^2=z$ $\partial / \partial \overline{z} |z|^2=\overline{z}$?

Comment: Nope. Remember that $|z|^2=z\bar z$.

Comment: ah yes, thank you